# How to get the current instance of an object from a C function

Tags: objective-c, c, runtime

I implemented a C callback in the implementation of an object which is used by a function from a private framework, so I have no control on the arguments passed to the callback. I would like to use `self` from the callback. Thanks.

EDIT:

MyObject.h/.m

```
#import "PrivateFramework.h"
@interface MyObject : NSObject    

-(void) start;  

@end  

void callback(void* arg1, int arg2);  
void callback(void* arg1, int arg2) {  

 /* 
   here I would like to use self (current instance of the object) but
    I can't pass a pointer to the instance in the callback since I don't
    control what is passed to it.
 */



@implementation MyObject

-(void)start {  

    // this function is inside a private framework.
    PrivateFunction(&callback);  
 }
@end
```

Comment: This is confusing. Please show some code.

Comment: Sorry to be blunt, but that is incomprehensible.

Comment: How many callbacks can be in progress at any one time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of options:

1. Use a singleton to manage the process
2. Add a 'class' variable (file level static) to hold the requesting instance

   `static MyObject *callbackResponder = nil;`

This would probably go between your #imports and @implementation in the .m file.

Comment: There are no class variables in Objective-C.

Comment: Updated the clarify the abuse of terminology.

Comment: Thanks! Now I see what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of a callback is what blocks were created for.  I would look into the Block Programming Guide.  It's not a C-style callback, but it has a similar use.